# Finding the epoch time for current datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get the epoch time of the current date time?

x = current epoch time

y = current epoch time - epoch time 30 days

```
import time

date_time = datetime.now()

pattern = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'

epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))

print (epoch)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module has a timestamp method:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time = datetime.now()
epoch_time = int(date_time.timestamp())
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime , timedelta

today = datetime.now()
today_30 = (today - timedelta(days = 30) )
today_epoch = int(today.timestamp())
print(today_epoch)
today_30_epoch = int(today_30.timestamp())
print(today_30_epoch)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

epoch_time = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())

print(epoch_time)
```

Comment: Why use the unbound method? Why not just call it on the datetime object returned by `.now()` directly?